# Should I include my StackExchange profile in my CV?

Tags: job-search, cv

I've been thinking that sometimes here on Stack Exchange, people make very good questions and give very good answers, in my case, I have learnt a lot from the community and when I post a question I try to make an effort to formulate it in a proper manner to avoid downvoting, so, when applying for a job or an academic position, would be correct to also make a reference of your Stack Exchange profile?

I believe that people that are hiring you, may have a better glimpse of you interests, what you know and what you don't know from the answers and questions that you make, so, is it a good idea to also show it?

Comment: Nobody cares, but are you sure you want anyone to be able to look at every post you made with a fine toothed comb?

Comment: What field? ...

Comment: well,  I was thinking in physics, math, programming, electrical engineering ... I don't now, at least, those are my interests

Comment: my question seems to be a duplicate. Do I delete it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may get a small bump by being a good *answerer* on the technical stacks, like Physics or Cross Validated. I've heard MathOverflow in particular has a decent recognition among mathematicians. Especially if you are applying for a teaching position, showing a good track record wouldn't hurt, even if only 1 in 25 people have heard of Stack Exchange (which would be a very high proportion in my experience).

By "good" I'm thinking of rep north of 5,000 at least, but I'm not familiar with the standards of those Stacks in particular.

That said, your thought about:

> I have learnt a lot from the community and when I post a question I try to make an effort to formulate it in a proper manner to avoid downvoting

... is, I'm sorry to say, pretty meaningless and confusing to explain to someone looking to hire you in an academic position. No one cares that you didn't get downvoted when asking a question online. That is basically the bare minimum to participate in these sites, even though I do acknowledge the communities can sometimes be harsh.

Answer (score 3):

If:

- the person specification for the job calls for skill X; and
- you think to yourself "I demonstrated skill X in StackExchange post Y"; and
- your StackExchange history doesn't contain anything likely to be offensive or embarrassing (given your user name, check the recruiter isn't a descendant of the house of Valois)

then it might well be beneficial to refer to StackExchange (although perhaps to the specific post Y, rather than to your profile).